# Tortoise SVN Redirect Cycle [CENTOS 5.8 / WHM]

Tags: apache, svn, tortoisesvn, centos, whm

Hoping somebody can shed some guru-knowledge here as we've been racking our brains trying to figure out what is causing this error.

We're running WHM/CPanel on CENTOS 5.8

We have a sub-domain specifically set up to server as an svn repository.
We've created the VirtualHost directory and config file. The config file looks like the following:

```
<IfModule mod_dav_svn.c>
 <Location />
  DAV svn
  SVNParentPath /home/<username>/public_html/svn
  SVNListParentPath On
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "SVN Repo"
  AuthUserFile /home/<username>/.svn.htpasswd
  Require valid-user
 </Location>
</IfModule>
```

We're using SVNParentPath because we will have multiple repositories.

Our repo's are created using svnadmin create

They show up fine when we navigate to them in a browser. We can see the top level folders. When we click into them all we see is the revision number. I'm pretty sure this is normal.

In Tortoise we connect to the repo like: http://svn.ourserver.com/reponame

We've been through any and every forum post we can think of and just cannot get passed the redirect cycle. Any knowledge will be greatly appreciated.

*edit*
I should add that we are getting the authentication windows so I believe that that part is setup correctly.

Comment: Why is it redirecting? Do you have a redirect configured in your `.htaccess`? When you navigate to them in the browser, is that on the same machine that you're running tortoisesvn?

Comment: That's the question. I really do not know why it's redirecting. There isn't any redirects configured in the .htaccess that I know of. The url is on a different machine outside of our network - though I just learned that it's only visible when on our network (strange?) TortoiseSVN is ran from my machine. In other words, we're not running a localhost svn. I'm starting to wonder if it has something to do with a firewall setting on centos or something. I'll admit that I'm pretty green in that area and don't know what to look for.

Comment: To me it sounds more like an apache / network issue, and svn is a red herring (although its been quite a while since I've played with it). I would try hosting a simple html file to see if that renders ok. The only flaw with that theory is the fact that you can browse your repo ok in a browser...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out I think this was more of a misunderstanding of how svn is setup and how tortoiseSVN needs to access it. Tortoise can't check out multiple projects (which we knew.) What we overlooked is that creating a repository, isn't the same as creating a project.

Once we converted the svn.mydomain.com to be a repo itself, created a project within that, we were able to check it out without error.

I want to thank everyone that tried to help. I really appreciate your time.

Answer (score 1):

- Repo location in site-root may have big bad impact later (if you'll have not-dav parts of site under ROOT)
- `SVNParentPath /home/<username>/public_html/svn/` (**trailing slash**) will be better, can't recall why

Comment: Well it's not the main site's root. This subdomain will be used specifically for svn repos. Also, we have tried the trailing slash without any luck. Thanks for the reply :)

Comment: @Veo - just for testing, try location below root and repository URL with trailing slash. BTW, reading Apache's logs may give some ideas

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance; could you elaborate on "location below root" please? Regarding the logs - I really didn't see anything in there. There were a few [500,#2] errors, but those were due to the lack of a favicon.ico file. In the domlogs for the account there was something about -0500. I'll boot up my dev machine and post a few lines in the case they are useful.

Comment: @Veo - "location below root" means just "Try to use `<location /somedir/>`" instead of /. For Apacche-log - you can create logs with SVN-commands in it instead of pure WebDAV (read SVN-book, can't recall exact syntax) and extended error-messaging.

Comment: @Veo - additional idea is forgot (for some time) about GUI and debug repo-access from CLI. `svn ls REPO-URL` may output useful info

Comment: Yeah there isn't anything in the logs related to this to post.

Comment: I could be doing something wrong as I'm somewhat new to this, but, SSH'd into the server, ran svn ls path/to/repo/ and it gave E155007 path/to/repo is not a working copy

Comment: @Veo - from remote location with svn-client `svn ls URL` - URL, not local path: as `svn ls http://mayorat.ursinecorner.ru:8088/svn/Hello` (existing my live repo)

Comment: installed sliksvn and ran svn ls http://svn.server.com/repo and it said "Redirecting to URL 'http://svn.server.com/repo':" (twice) and then "svn: E195019: Redirect cycle detected for url 'http://svn.server.com/repo'

Comment: Tried the location below root. Same result - the redirect of the url. One thing that I just recently learned (like 5 minutes ago) is that the url isn't visible outside of my lan. I had to vpn into my network for it to show up. I'm wondering if this could be causing the issue. Though, one would think that being on the network it would work.